# Inconsistent icons in Ubuntu Unity

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I've downloaded IntelliJ Idea, then just unziped it and run it by execute `idea.sh` in terminal and made a new project. I wanted to see what would happen if I simply `right click on icon at the left side bar in Unity -> lock to Launcher` instead of standard way of making new `idea.desktop` file also used for making Eclipse launcher icon. And it just made icon on launcher wich runs that particular project. After that I've made `idea.desktop` icon standard way and it looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Type=Application
Exec=idea.sh
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/idea/idea-IC-135.909/bin/idea.png
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=IntelliJ IDEA
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

Now when I click on that standard `idea.desktop` it runs another instance of application (that one which I've made with `right click on icon on left side bar in Unity -> lock to Launcher`) and it results with situation shown on image below.
[image: result situation]

I am trying to find this `something.desktop` icon which I have made with `lock to Launcher` if any and delete it, but I can't find it in `/usr/share/applications`.

- What Ubuntu actually does when I click on `lock to Launcher`?
- Whether it creates some `.desktop` file or something else?
- How can I delete icon made by `lock to Launcher`?

Comment: you can unlock the icon form launcher and then delete it

Comment: 'delete it' how?
Icon is already unlocked from launcher but it is still present in Unity Dash and it is launched when i click on idea.desktop as shown on image in question.

Comment: Finally someone els has this problem, I've had this problem on one machine for one app (firefox) since 12.10.  And found this because this week a new machine and a different app (nautilus) has acquired this problem.  I've been unable to express what the problem is to be able to form a useful google search to find where or how to log the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I just resolved where firefox was creating these "evil twin" entries.  The process involved in matching running applications to icons is called `bamfdaemon`. Firstly find your session's version of this daemon:

```
$ ps x | grep bamf
1147 pts/11   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto bamf
2597 ?        Sl     0:22 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon
```

Now we're going to trace the startup of your application - so close it down.

```
$ strace -o ~/bamf.txt -p 2597
```

Now I got a warning about being unable to connect to that pid, so I re-ran it with `sudo`.

Start your app and wait until the icon appears.  Then return to your strace instance and kill it with `Ctrl-C`.

Now look through the ~/bamf.txt file - what I found was bamf notices my new process (firefox)

```
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 3, -1) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\241\10\353\220,\0\300\2\243\1\0\0new: ID=\"compiz-2674"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 224
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\241\10\353\220,\0\300\2\244\1\0\0ting\\ Firefox\\ Web\\ "..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 96
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\241\10\353\220,\0\300\2\244\1\0\0ications/firefox.des"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 64
```

Then looks up the executable (for firefox its in lib), then opens the `.desktop` file it found as best match:

```
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb5854000
_llseek(12, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)           = 0
read(12, "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox\0", 4096) = 25
read(12, "", 3072)                      = 0
close(12)                               = 0
munmap(0xb5854000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/share/applications/firefox-4.0.desktop", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 12
fstat64(12, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3740, ...}) = 0
read(12, "[Desktop Entry]\nVersion=1.0\nName"..., 4096) = 3740
read(12, "", 4096)                      = 0
close(12)                               = 0
```

Hmmm,... thats funny - firefox-4.0 was a beta version I installed yonks ago, so it looks for the exec file in the `.desktop`:

```
access("/opt/firefox-4.0/firefox", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {13405, 712196198}) = 0
write(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x9319698, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x9308780, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
```

And in my case I got a bad icon because that executable has been gone since 2011!  Move that `.destkop` out of the way and suddenly firefox matches its icon again.

In your case you can probably stop at the point where you see which `.desktop` file it opens - thats the one you'll want to delete.